GRUB vs two Linux distributions
I am trying to use two Linux distributions on one computer. And it goes like this:

one GRUB (GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false) - the first system boots, the second bad shim signature; I get the point, I don't disable secure boot

each system has a boot partition and its GRUB - I can choose the order from BIOS and boot both systems. I try in the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file:



set root='hd1,gpt1' and chainloader +1 - result Bad shim signature

set root='hd1,gpt1' and chainloader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi - result file not found



in the GRUB console, I type ls - it displays two HDDs (no system), one SSD as hd3 (?) with the first system, the end, the second SSD with the second system is missing; now surprise: I type exit and I have.... GRUB menu of the second system, it works, just how? I go back to the GRUB console (first system), exit, GRUB of the first system.... again, ls, exit, second system.... again, ls, exit, first system, again, ls, exit, second system.... each time booting up a system and resetting it again.

Summary: Two Linux distributions (Kubuntu and Mint), on two different drives (NVMe M.2 SSD). Currently each distribution has its own partition with its own GRUB. Two data HDDs are also present on the system.
Anybody know how to make the file 40_custom add a menu to start the GRUB of the second system? Or any other way to boot a second system with secure boot enabled without changes to the BIOS?
I hope I've written this clearly - meaning that deepl.com has translated it well.
Solution:

use sudo blkid command to correctly locate the disk and partition from GRUB of the other system, remember, save UUID
in GRUB console (c key) use ls -l to locate partition with found UUID, remember hdX,gptX
use the ls (hdX,gptX)/efi command to check the path to the grubx64.efi file (may be different for different distributions) and save it
edit the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file by adding an entry:

    menuentry “Linux Mint” {
    insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        set root='hd3,gpt1' # Change to the appropriate EFI partition for Mint
        chainloader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi # Change to the correct path for Mint
    }



sudo update-grub

On the second system, you can add a similar entry for the partition with the first GRUB, but on my system it shows something like this EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1: 0x8000000000000000b, so I gave up.

Does it work with Secure boot off? Grub normally uses configfile to load another grub stanza (or file with boot stanzas). Example is in your ESP as grub in ESP uses configfile & UUID to find grub in your install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus Some examples of boot stanza in 40_custom. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive
